# How does setting up contractId as the supply key impact minting tokens using with Hedera Token Service/Smart Contract?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I am working on a project that involves minting tokens using the Hedera Token Service (HTS) and smart contracts. I have a question regarding the setup of the contractId as the supply key for the token.

How does setting the contractId as the supply key impact the process of minting tokens using the Hedera SDK and smart contracts? Are there any significant differences compared to using an account ID as the supply key?
When creating and signing transactions that involve minting tokens, how can I sign the transaction with the contractId as the supply key? Are there any specific steps or methods that I should use?
I have researched the Hedera documentation and tried to find relevant examples or discussions, but I have not been able to find a clear answer to my question.

Any insights or guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Contract ID as a supply key will allow the smart contract to mint tokens on HTS. Smart Contracts on Hedera can call Hedera Token Service (HTS) thorugh precompile smart contract. You can take a look the detail about the implementation of precompile smart contract from [HIP-206](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-206)

Also feel free to take a look at the example code [here](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/tree/develop/examples/precompile-example)